# How do I formulate this proof that these spaces are not deform retracts?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given $B = \{(x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 = 1, z^2 \leq 1\}$, $A = B \cup \{(x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1, z^2 = 1\}$, prove that $B$ isn't a retract of $A$.
Intuitively, I notice straight away that the fundamental group of B is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and the fundamental group of $A$ is trivial.
If we were to assume that there exists a retract from $A$ to $B$, $f$, then $f\circ \gamma = \gamma$ for a loop on $B$. Then I want to get a contradiction using the fundamental groups.

My two biggest problems are that I don't know how to formally prove my intuitions about the fundamental groups of $A$,$B$ and that I don't know how to use the induced homomorphism to reach a contradiction.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the unit circle is a retract of the cylinder $B$, they are homotopy equivalent, and so have isomorphic fundamental groups. Since the unit disc is a retract of the full-cylinder $A$, they are also homotopy equivalent, and so have isomorphic fundamental groups. Since the unit-disc is contractible, $A$ has a trivial fundamental group whereas $B$ does not, as you already have guessed. Now, if $B$ is a retract of $A$, $i:B\to A$ the inclusion map, and $r:A\to B$ the retract mapping such that $ri$ is the identity on $B$, then $i$ induces a homomorphism $F(i):\pi_1(B)\to \pi_1(A)$, and $r$ induces a homomorphism $F(r):\pi_1(A)\to\pi_1(B)$, and you must have that $F(r)F(i)$ equals the identity of $\pi_1(B)$. But that is not possible if $\pi_1(A)$ is trivial and $\pi_1(B)$ is not.

Comment: Thanks for this! Why is it that two homotopy equivalent spaces have the same fundamental group?

Comment: Note that the circle and cylinder are homotopy equivalent because one is a _deformation retract_ of the other. Just being a retract is not enough to imply homotopy equivalence.